# Using 2 Mouses in blender

Tags: animation

Okay so for the  past month or 2 I have been studying this new animating technique called real time animating. As far as I know the technique was founded by Tvori and used in VR a lot. Basically you click play on the timeline and animate in realtime. Then you go back, slow down the frame rate and you continue to play the timeline while animating in real time as it plays.

The results I got were amazing and I love what I am getting but the problem is I am limited by xy and z. Being on PC you only have access to two points of the plain either x and y or x and z or y and z but never all 3. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to bind the axis z to another mouse and use two of them or to bind it to say scroll wheel so I can scroll for the z axis. I would love a solution to be able to have access to XY and Z... preferably without spending the money on a new VR headset...

Comment: Interesting idea... I imagine having a mouse bound to the XY plane and control the Z position with a flight simulator hand throttle control with left hand.

Comment: yeah I am currently trying to figure out how to write a simple script so I could bind the z axis to my mouse. Unfortunately there isn't a tutorial alive that will give me a straight answer of how to put the code to my mouse

Comment: Oh my lawrd I finally found someone that gave me an answer... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAGWHym0dqI&t=98s&ab_channel=rybread